# Using gsub on cloned hash in Ruby modifies original

Tags: ruby, clone

I'm facing a problem in which I can't substitute a string in a cloned hash without affecting its original. I'd better explain using an example:

```
product_attributes = raw_attributes.clone

# do some stuff on product_attributes like removing hash elements using "select!"

puts product_attributes[:code]
# => 64020-001
puts raw_attributes[:code]
# => 64020-001

product_attributes[:code].gsub!(/[\/|\-][0-9\.]*$/, "")

puts product_attributes[:code]
# => 64020
puts raw_attributes[:code]
# => 64020
```

I use Ruby 1.9.3p327 on OSX.

Is this a known issue (or even a feature)? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I copy a hash in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157399/how-do-i-copy-a-hash-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clone` only makes a shallow copy of the array, so the elements are copied over rather than cloned themselves. See [What's the most efficient way to deep copy an object in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643432/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-copy-an-object-in-ruby) for some good discussion about how to do a deep copy efficiently.

If you just need to deep clone this one value:

```
product_attributes = raw_attributes.clone
product_attributes[:code] = product_attributes[:code].clone
```

Comment: Oh, that does make sense. Thank you. 
I made pretty dramatic title :) I'd better go to read a book.